# SharePoint Powershell - Update MultiValue MMD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, term-store, multiple-values

I am trying to update multiple values to a managed metadata field in sharepoint library. Below is my code which works for single item

```
$MMSField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$item.Fields[$FieldName]
if($Term) # here $Term is the value which exists in termstore
{
$MMSField.setFieldValue($item,$Term) 
$Item.SystemUpdate()
}
```

This code doesn't work for multiple values. 
I have all the values coming from a .CSV file.

Eg:

```
ID   ,  Value
1212 , .Net;Java;C#;
1213 , .Net
1211 , Java
```

I want to update multiple values which are separated using semicolon as shown above .csv format.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!